# Can I use a static routing table in my router to fix a path to a particular server on the public web?

Tags: networking, router, static-routes

I am trying to improve my internet performance and using Speedtest.net I can see that a particular server on the public web has much faster ping times and bandwidth than others. Can I use a static routing table in my router to fix a path to this particular server on the public web? And if I do so is it likely to improve my web performance?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you really control with the routing table is the next hop.  To say it differently you control which system, on a network you are directly connected to, a packet will be forwarded to for a specific network or address.  After the packet leaves your system it is completely up to the device that received your packet to decide what to do next.